# Why do NOT process.join() return when the process terminates?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

My code is following:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
task_queue = Queue(TASK_QUEUE_SIZE)
result_queue = Queue()

def worker_thread(worker_id, task_queue, result_queue):
    # consume task_queue and put result into result_queue
    # if task is None, it prints closed message and returns 0
    ...

workers = [Process(target=worker_thread, args=(i, task_queue, result_queue)) 
           for i in range(NUM_OF_THREADS)]
for w in workers:
    w.start()

# put task into task_queue, read result from result_queue...
# all done. try to exit.

print('waiting 120 seconds for workers...')
time.sleep(120)  # wait long enough for workers return
for no, w in enumerate(workers):
    print(f'joining worker #{no}')
    w.join(1)
    print(f'worker #{no} is_alive: {w.is_alive()} exitcode: {w.exitcode}')
```

This program generate log like this:

```
pending jobs: 1
worker #0 is started.
waiting 120 seconds for workers...
worker #0 got task id: 123
worker #0 got result for task id: 123
worker #0 is closed.
joining worker #0
worker #0 isalive: False exitcode: 0
```

**If I use w.join(), it will wait forever**. Very strange. Could you give me some clue? Thank you in advance.

====

UPDATE: I found my code **sometimes** wait forever. If logging is in the form of my original post, it will safe exit. However, if it like below [use join(1)], it will be stuck forever. It is strange that worker #0 prints closed message but does not exit.

```
waiting 120 seconds for workers...
worker #0 got result id: 123
worker #0 is closed.
joining worker #0
worker #0 isalive: True exitcode: None


def worker_thread(worker_id: int, task_queue, result_queue):
    print(f'worker #{worker_id} is started.')

    while 1:
        try:
            t = task_queue.get()
            if t is None:
                break
            r = do_task(t)
            if r:
                result_queue.put((t, r))
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'[FATAL] worker #{worker_id} got unknown error on task {t}.\nReason: {type(e)} {e}')
            traceback.print_exc()
            continue

    print(f'worker #{worker_id} is closed.')
    return 0
```

Comment: What is the implementation of `worker_thread`? Using `join()` without any arguments would give it no timeout, hence it will wait forever or until the process completed. Given that it is waiting forever, your `worker_thread` process might never end because of its implementation

Comment: @Andreas the logging shows worker_thread printed close message and returns 0. Therefore, I think, it exits before join().